# Apache rewrite HTTPS - HTTPS not working

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

I'm trying to redirect https://www.bar.com to https://www.foo.com. Why doesn't the below Apache configuration do this? (I get a 200 OK when I access https://www.bar.com, which I have pointing at localhost for testing.)

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}  www\.bar\.com [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteRule ^/?(.*)        https://www.foo.com/$1 [L,R,NE]
```

Comment: What do you see when you enable your `RewriteLog`?

Comment: Nothing. I have tried for hours to GET a rewrite log, and it logs nothing. You can imagine my frustration.

Comment: Can you show us your `RewriteLog` configuration?  And any surrounding `VirtualHost` block?  And can you verify that you're actually seeing entries in your access log when you make requests?

Comment: RewriteLog "/tmp/rewrite.log"
RewriteLogLevel 8

This is in a <VirtualHost _default_:443> block. `/tmp/rewrite.log` gets created but nothing is logged to it. And yes, I see access log entries.

Comment: Should mention this is 2.2.22 on OSX.

Comment: In general, when people ask for more information you should update the question rather than post it in a comment because comment formatting is terrible for this sort of thing.